# How to run test again if it fails with unittest

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I have a test suit that is ruined by HTMLRunner:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(MyForms))
    dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
    buf = file("../TestReport" + "_" + dateTimeStamp + ".html", 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
         stream = buf,
         title = 'PDFFiller tests', # Title of report
         description = 'Test results' # Description of report
         )
    runner.run(suite)
```

How can I upgrade my code to run test again if it fails?

Note: I heard that it is not right to run test twice, but I need to rerun it.

Comment: Why don't you fix the test instead?

Comment: I can't understand the reason why it sometimes failed and sometimes not. And it always different tests.

Comment: @Michael: you'll still have to understand that as it could indicate a transient bug in your code. Ignoring unittests that sometimes fail is not a good strategy.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, but how can I find the reason when test sometimes fils and sometimes not.

Comment: That depends on your code and your test. That's too broad a subject to discuss here, certainly without any code. If you want to ask about that, produce a small code sample that demonstrates the problem, and post a question about that instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, ok. But my question still opened.

Comment: Yes, and I gave my advice, as a comment: don't ignore that test failure.

Comment: If at first it doesn't succeed, run again...and again....and again....

Comment: @Arran, I have HTML report and want to show tests that successfully runned after second try as passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try save the test as a function and run it in a loop with a try/except. The try/except will allow you to continue after the failure. The loop will allow you to control how many times you run the test.

```
def test(variables go here):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(MyForms))
        dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
        buf = file("../TestReport" + "_" + dateTimeStamp + ".html", 'wb')
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
             stream = buf,
             title = 'PDFFiller tests', # Title of report
             description = 'Test results' # Description of report
             )
        runner.run(suite)

VariableMarkerOfTestStatus = 0 #This variable is just a way of telling if the test failed or not
#tempCounter = 0 #UNCOMMENT IF YOU WANT TO LIMIT THE NUMBER OF TIMES THIS RUNS

while VariableMarkerOfTestStatus < 1:  #This will loop until it passes. 
    try: test(variables go here)
    except: VariableMarkerOfTestStatus -=1

    #UNCOMMENT IF YOU WANT TO LIMIT THE NUMBER OF TIMES THIS RUNS
    #if VariableMarkerOfTestStatus < 0:
    #    tempCounter+=1
    #    if tempCounter > 2: # 2 represents the number of times the test is allowed to fail
    #        test(variables go here) # If it has failed twice, run it once more so that the error displays
    #

    VariableMarkerOfTestStatus+=1
```